# SQL SELECT query to set values with same id on different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a table with two columns: 'id' and 'type'. There can be multiple rows with the same id, but a type cannot be used more than once for each id. Example:

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | type-1 |
| 1 | type-2 |
| 1 | type-3 |
| 2 | type-1 |
| 2 | type-2 |

I would like to construct a SELECT query which from the table above, would take every id and output a string containing all the types with the same id. Example:

| id | types |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | type-1,type-2,type-3 |
| 2 | type-1,type-2 |

However, I do not know how I can do this. Can someone help, please?

Comment: @forpas Your duplicate link is not specific enough (q.v. one of the deleted answers below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` with an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT id,
      GROUP_CONCAT(type ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(type, '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED)) AS types
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```